# The type of a grave

Tags: adjectives

[image]

What would this sort of grave be called which is not earth-pit now? What adjective will best describe it?

A. Constructed grave

B. Built grave

C. Plastered grave

D. Masonry-built grave

E. Structured grave

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the 'grave' is the hole in the ground, not any masonry that decorates or marks it. However, it is common for the entire thing to be collectively referred to as 'a grave'.

In British English, the stone that marks a dug grave is called a *headstone*.

When the grave is raised as in the photograph, we either call that a *raised grave* or a *tomb*. The inscription may then be called a *tombstone*.

There are likely many other English words for these owing to different cultures and dialects.

Comment: what about 'structured grave'? i mean does it make sense? maybe it is not standard though.

Comment: No, not "structured".  There may be some technical terminology used by funeral directors for different types of grave memorial structures, but such terms are not in general use.  To me these are just "graves", the fact that there is a little stone ledge doesn't mean it has a special name, though as Astralbee suggests "raised grave" would be a reasonable description, even though I've not see that phrase before.

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqii This page may be useful (https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/raised-grave.html) the images have tags. 'Raised grave' is used as I suggested, but also 'above ground grave'.

Answer (score 1):

In the photograph, one can see that the grave is actually *raised* slightly, so I guess you can call this a "raised grave".

"tomb" can also be used here, but the definition of tomb from Oxford Languages is

> a large vault, typically an underground one, for burying the dead

Since it depicts a *underground "vault"*, this may not be useable, although you *can* if you want.

So in this case, I suggest you use "raised grave" or simply "grave", as the grave is not really raised much off the ground.

"structured/built grave" is quite vague, "structured grave" could just mean the grave is structured, as in built solidly, which doesn't fit this context.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some memorial masons' websites, it seems the stone surround is called a *kerb* in Britain (the same term as we use for the stone edging of the pavement at the side of a road.) NB American terminology is different. However, in British cemeteries the kerb isn't normally as high as the ones in your photo.